# failure to build rust-libc using cargo when rustc is musl-enabled

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, musl

I successfully created a `musl` configured `rustc` by following [this link](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/doc/trpl/advanced-linking.md)

My attempt to build a project (which builds fine using non-musl configured rust) failed when I used `cargo rustc -- --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

```
 'error: could not find crate `libc` with expected target triple x86_64-unknown-linux-musl'
```

Then, I tried to create `rust-libc` library using the code from crate. To be more accurate, I used the command provided by `cargo` to build `rust-libc`, I've only added `--target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` to the command.  This time it failed reporting:

```
'error: could not find native static library `c`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?`'
```

I have two questions:

- Is it mandatory to build `musl` configured `cargo` to be able to use `cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`?
- How can I address this:

  ```
  'error: could not find native static library `c`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?'
  ```

Comment: You wrote that you typed "cargo rustc -- --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl" . Is there a "rustc" option of cargo or should that be "build"? "cargo build" works without musl.

Comment: cargo build works, but the built library does not have the dependencies statically linked.

Comment: Your first question should probably be reworded. "in order to use cargo build" must need something else, because you are saying you can use "cargo build".  Can you build a fully statically-linked executable by calling rustc directly the way they did at the bottom of the instruction page you linked to?

Comment: yes, I created the example.rs in the link and verified it having no dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me to build libc:

> rustc --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl /address-of-libc/lib.rs --crate-name libc --crate-type lib -L /address-of-musldist/musldist/lib/ --out-dir=/your-chosen-address/target --cfg feature=\"default\" --cfg feature=\"cargo-build\" --emit=dep-info,link